# Singapore airport to hotel late at night

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, singapore, taxis

I will arrive at Singapore airport late at night/early in the morning, probably around 1:00 AM before I can get out. I need to travel to my hotel, the Parkroyal on Beach Road, about an hour away according to Google maps.

In general I don't mind taking public transport, but it doesn't look as if it runs that late. Are taxis generally available at the airport that late? If I should reserve one, is there a simple way to do so on line? Are Uber/Lyft options in Singapore? Are there other alternatives I'm missing?

*Edit* We took a taxi, and it was quick (25 minutes), easy (no line at the airport, several taxis waiting), and inexpensive (around $25 Singapore, which I split with two other people heading to the same place).

Comment: In any large airport you will have taxis at any time there are incoming flights. Never arrived in Singapore at that time, but I would be very surprised if there weren’t many taxis waiting.

Comment: Note that there are lots of flights arriving around that time, and even flights arriving much later in the night, so I would personally not worry about it for a minute (unless you are arriving on New Year’s Day).

Comment: Several years ago I had no problem with getting a taxi to near the city center from the airport. Landed around your 1AM time, made it to the hotel just fine. Very little traffic then!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like there's a shuttle bus that operates 24 hours for SGD 9.00. Your hotel is listed. Limited to one item of luggage. Can be booked in advance.

https://cityshuttle.com.sg/cityshuttlepublic/BookingDetails.aspx?Type=2

Obviously if you have more than one piece of luggage, are more than a solo traveler or are going to be especially tired and/or busy the next day, a taxi could make more sense. It's only about 20km, so it should be more like 20-30 minutes.

Comment: Wow, good find! I spent 15 minutes poking around and didn’t find this, starting from my hotel’s site.

Answer (score 5):

The MRT stops at around 11:30 from Airport and busses shortly after 12 AM. You have no options, but to take a cab.

Uber and Lyft are not available in Singapore. You can install Grab or GoJEK for ride-hailing. For normal metered cab, you have to stand in queue and usually at those time, in my experience, its a long wait.

Also, Grab/GoJEK will be generally cheaper than a normal cab. Install it beforehand, connect to Airport WiFi (You will have to provide a passport number from the Kiosk) and book the cab. Ask for grab pickup directions, which is I think one level down. There will be door number, which you can provide in the app for accurate pickup.

**Update:** WiFi doesn't need a passport number now. You can simply connect.

Comment: I had no problem getting a cab at the airport any of the times I arrived, but can confirm locals use Grab and it's super quick. Getting the wifi password will be your longest step :-)

Comment: A cab is always available. Its the waiting time when you are all tired from the flight that makes it frustrating. I usually book a grab/gojek even before clearing immigration.

Comment: @AnishSheela There is a short "taxi peak hour" in Changi (around 11 PM IIRC), but even this depends on the terminal and if the OP arrives after 1 AM this should have cleared out.  The queues usually move *very* fast anyway.

Comment: By the way, booking grab/gojek before clearing immigration doesn't apply to visitors. It may be tricky to find the place where you can take taxi. For residents with automated clearance, immigration is superfast all the time.